# UNION ALL MYSQL is really slow

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, union-all

I have a query in mysql with 2 select from's. When I run these queries individually they run quick within 1 second. But when I combine them with union all, the website freeze's and it takes atleast 20 seconds for the same query to execute in union all.

Any idea why this happens? Can't figure it out.

See the query below:

```
SELECT p.user_id, p.description, p.post_id, p.created_at, ps.username AS size_name, ps.username AS user_name, ps.avatar AS avatar, pz.title AS title, pz.slug AS slug 
FROM comments p 
JOIN users ps ON ps.id = p.user_id 
JOIN posts pz ON pz.id = p.post_id 

UNION ALL

SELECT p2.user_id, p2.description, p2.post_id, p2.created_at, ps2.username AS size_name, ps2.username AS user_name, ps2.avatar AS avatar, pz2.title AS title, pz2.slug AS slug 
FROM reply p2 
JOIN users ps2 ON ps2.id = p2.user_id 
JOIN posts pz2 ON pz2.id = p2.post_id 

order by created_at DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: How many rows do each of the subqueries return?

Comment: @Barmar about 2M each.

Comment: Do ORDER BY and LIMIT 10 in each SELECT first. Then do it on the UNION ALL result too.

Comment: Your problem is the ORDER BY clause. The UNION needs to get all records, and then sort them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before merging with `UNION`, reduce the size of the tables returned by each subquery. Since you only want the top 10, you only need the top 10 of each subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    (SELECT p.user_id, p.description, p.post_id, p.created_at, ps.username AS size_name, ps.username AS user_name, ps.avatar AS avatar, pz.title AS title, pz.slug AS slug 
    FROM comments p 
    JOIN users ps ON ps.id = p.user_id 
    JOIN posts pz ON pz.id = p.post_id 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 10) 
    
    UNION ALL
    
    (
    SELECT p2.user_id, p2.description, p2.post_id, p2.created_at, ps2.username AS size_name, ps2.username AS user_name, ps2.avatar AS avatar, pz2.title AS title, pz2.slug AS slug 
    FROM reply p2 
    JOIN users ps2 ON ps2.id = p2.user_id 
    JOIN posts pz2 ON pz2.id = p2.post_id 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 10)
) AS x
order by created_at DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: you can just use parentheses, not a subquery, to have order by/limit for the individual queries; see my answer

Comment: But you need an outer select to filter it to the top 10 of the combined queries.

Comment: no, you don't.  you can order & limit the individual queries and order and limit the union as a whole too

Comment: oh, didn't know you could do it like you show.

Answer (score 1):

UNION defaults to UNION DISTINCT.  If you want UNION ALL, explictly say that (and you should, wherever possible, since UNION DISTINCT has to do a lot of work to make them distinct).

The other thing is that the order by and limit apply to the query as a whole.  You may want to make each unioned query have them too.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html:

> ORDER BY and LIMIT in Unions
>
> To apply an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to an individual SELECT, parenthesize the SELECT and place the clause inside the parentheses:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

If your fast individual versions did have those, that should help.  So something like this:

```
(SELECT p.user_id, p.description, p.post_id, p.created_at, ps.username AS size_name, ps.username AS user_name, ps.avatar AS avatar, pz.title AS title, pz.slug AS slug 
FROM comments p 
JOIN users ps ON ps.id = p.user_id 
JOIN posts pz ON pz.id = p.post_id 
order by created_at DESC 
LIMIT 10)

UNION ALL

(SELECT p2.user_id, p2.description, p2.post_id, p2.created_at, ps2.username AS size_name, ps2.username AS user_name, ps2.avatar AS avatar, pz2.title AS title, pz2.slug AS slug 
FROM reply p2 
JOIN users ps2 ON ps2.id = p2.user_id 
JOIN posts pz2 ON pz2.id = p2.post_id 
order by created_at DESC 
LIMIT 10)

order by created_at DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I forgot to add the UNION ALL here on stackoverflow. I changed it. Thank you.

Comment: That query will return just 2 rows; 10 and 11.

Comment: This will return up to 20 rows.

Comment: @Barmar, the first SELECT will return up to 10 rows, all value 10. The second SELECT will return up to 10 rows, all value 11. **UNION** will remove duplicates and return just one 10 and one 11 (if both values exist.)

Comment: That's not representative of the original query, since they want the top 10 rows from two combined queries.

Comment: since the query from the documentation seemed to confuse some of you, added one customized to this question